# POSIXts error when quit Rstudio

Tags: r

When I tried to close Rstudio in Mac I get the following error:

```
   Error in as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
      argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Have not tried to reisntall Rstudio as i am hoping can fix the issue.

this are the packages loaded in session:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
```

These are the objects in the global env:

```
> ls()
[1] "csv"  "csv2" "csv3" "p"   
>
```

Have tried `base::q()` and `base::quit()` and get the same error.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.3     scales_0.4.1    ggplot2_2.2.1   bindrcpp_0.2    dplyr_0.7.1     lubridate_1.6.0 readr_1.1.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11     compiler_3.4.0   colourpicker_0.3 plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1        shinyjs_0.9.1   
 [7] tools_3.4.0      digest_0.6.12    jsonlite_1.5     tibble_1.3.3     gtable_0.2.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[13] rlang_0.1.1      rstudioapi_0.6   curl_2.7         stringr_1.2.0    knitr_1.16       htmlwidgets_0.8 
[19] hms_0.3          grid_3.4.0       glue_1.1.1       R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     htmltools_0.3.6 
[25] assertthat_0.2.0 mime_0.5         colorspace_1.3-2 xtable_1.8-2     httpuv_1.3.3     labeling_0.3    
[31] V8_1.5           stringi_1.1.5    miniUI_0.1.1     lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: what does `traceback()` report?

Comment: `5: as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))
4: date.default()
3: date()
2: cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
1: .Last()`

Comment: `date()` happy to accept ur solution @RichardTelford

Comment: Something has made a `.Last` function (hidden object because it starts with a `.` - unless you use `ls(all.names = TRUE)`. If you have a look at it, you might be able to work out what made it. You can probably delete it.

Comment: fixed! thanks @RichardTelford now I just need you to answer my question so I marked it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This could be because lubridate expects input but base::date() does not need it. Removing lubridate might solve the issue, or using base::date() instead. See [this](https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/issues/862) thread for a discussion on this issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: try ```detach("package:lubridate", unload=TRUE)``` instead of just ```detach```